# Facing huge layer 7 attack on port 3306

Tags: centos, security, iptables, fail2ban

I am facing huge attack of layer 7 on port 3306-

my iptables rules are good too

```
184  9568 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn/32 > 3 reject-with tcp-reset
 386K   20M REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn/32 > 2 reject-with tcp-reset
 334K  128M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED limit: avg 10/sec burst 15
  13M  772M REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 #conn/32 > 1 reject-with tcp-reset
```

Comment: The question is very scant in details. Can you quantify the huge attack? Is this a  single server at home, a SMB, a VPS in a cloud provider...why should you have MySQL open to the outside? DROP the packets, do not answer to them.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what your actual problem is. Port 3306 is MySQL, is the attacker trying to break into your database? If the DB should not be accessible from outside, you should perhaps drop all connection requests from outside (I normally consider sending any reply packets to an attacker an unnecessary courtesy...) If the attacker somehow consumes your inbound bandwidth, you might want to talk to your provider about what they can do at the network perimeter.

Comment: It should be not an *if*, the DB *ought* not to be directly exposed to the outside.

Comment: Yes, that "if" was meant like "if you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot, don't point a loaded gun at it..."